# How to search all snap packages for filename?

Tags: apt, package-management, snap

What is the snap equivalent to issuing

```
apt-file search X11/extensions/XKBrules.h # header file some repo uses who's compile fails as it cannot find this file

# ... above returns with

libxkbfile-dev: /usr/include/X11/extensions/XKBrules.h
```

above lets me identify which Ubuntu package `libxkbfile-dev` contains file `/usr/include/X11/extensions/XKBrules.h`

beauty of above is it searches ALL packages not just those already installed

How to identify which snap package contains a given filename ? ( even when I am yet to install that snap package )

---

On a new machine in order for above apt-file to work machine must have following run to install the latest index of all Ubuntu packages

```
sudo apt install apt-file -y  && sudo apt-file update
```

I am looking for the functional equivalent to this for snap packages

... Why ?  a common use case is :   if I am compiling someone else's code and a header file is missing so I need to know what package to install to get that missing header ( assuming that missing file actually lives in a package which it often does for Ubuntu packages and will increasingly do as projects migrate over to snap )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reported two relevant bugs in 2018:

- [bug 1748628 - `snap` should provide functionality to show files, which are included into non-installed snap (analog of `apt-file list`)](https://pad.lv/1748628)
- [bug 1748633 - `snap` should provide functionality to find non-installed snap which contain known file (analog of `apt-file search`)](https://pad.lv/1748633)

and both are marked as *WishList* so this functionality is not yet implemented.

Theoretically the `command-not-found` may help finding relevant snap name with known executable, but I do not know yet how to automate it.

Comment: cool ... I up marked both tickets to encourage someone to solve this

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg --listfiles <pkg>` (-L) seems to work on Snaps too. It can reverse search the package from a file with `dpkg -S <file>`.